# Перевод десятичного числа в двоичную систему

Tags: java

Я новичок, поставил себе задачу написать программу, которая будет переводить десятичное число в двоичную систему счисления. Пожалуйста, не пишите про велосипед. Конкретно сейчас пытаюсь реализовать следующее: цикл `for`, который будет делить на 2 итоговое число, которое получается в результате предыдущей операции деления:

```
int x = 13;
int y = 2;
int celoe, itog;
for (celoe = x; celoe < 2; celoe -= celoe / y) {
    itog = celoe / y;
    System.out.println(itog);
}
```

Не работает. Не могли бы объяснить почему?

Comment: На основе чего вывод, что не работает?

Comment: Советую перечитать главу о циклах for. В коде явная ошибка в его создании.

Comment: На выходе совершенно ничего не выдается. То, что ошибка - я и без того понимаю, я хочу получить конструктивную критику почему не работает. Должно получиться примерно следующее:
Сперва будет деление celoe(а она у нас равна 13) на y(что равно 2) после этой операции будет возвращено 6. Затем, согласно шагу, celoe уже будет равно 6 и в операции celoe/2 = будет возвращено 3 и тд..
    6
    3
должно возращаться в итоге

Comment: Ничего не выдаётся, потому что цикл ни разу не выполняется. У вас неправильное условие.

Comment: у вас даже в цикл не будет заходить. вы в начале цикла пишите `celoe = 13`, и просите выполнять цикл до тех пор, пока `celoe < 2`. У вас сразу же будет выход из цикла, т.к. начальное условие заведомо ложное. Поправьте начальное условие для начала.

Comment: Спасибо, Denis! Я проворонил > и <. Перепутал их, теперь всё работает как надо!